# How to proof the following function is always constant which satisfies $f\left( x \right) + a\int_{x - 1}^x {f\left( t \right)\,dt} $?

Tags: calculus, integration, functions

Suppose that $f(x)$ is a bounded continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$,and that there exists a positive number $a$ such that
$$f\left( x \right) + a\int_{x - 1}^x {f\left( t \right)\,dt} $$
is constant. Can anybody show that  $f$ is necessarily constant ?

Answer (score 8):

The proof below works for $a<1$.  Bugs are still being sorted out in the generalization.

---

First, note that $\int_{x-1}^x f(t)dt$ is differentiable, so $f(x) = C - \int_{x-1}^x f(t)dt$ is differentiable.

Next, we have $f'(x) = af(x-1) - af(x)$, so $|f'(x)| \leq a(|f(x-1)| + |f(x)|)$.  Since $f$ is bounded, this implies that $f'$ is bounded.

The crux: Fix $x$.  By the mean value theorem, there is some $y\in (x-1,x)$ with $f'(y) = f(x)-f(x-1)$, so $f'(x) = -af'(y)$.

Continuing in this manner, we find, for any $k$, some $y_k$ with $f'(x) = (-a)^k f'(y_k)$.  Letting $k\to\infty$, and using the fact that $f'$ is bounded, we find that $f'(x) = 0$.  This holds for all $x$, so $f$ is constant.

---

PhoemueX and I have both concluded that Taylor's Theorem proves that $f$ is analytic.  It's not obvious if this helps, but it feels significant, so I thought I'd include it.

Comment: Each time the mean value theorem is applied, the location of $y_k$ is only guaranteed to lie in the previous interval. So it's possible that the sequence of $y_k$ go off toward $\pm \infty,$ and then (since $f'$ is not necessarily bounded on $\mathbb{R}$ just from the $f$ bounded assumption) one gets no conclusion.

Comment: @coffeemath Didn't I show that $f'$ is bounded in the second paragraph?

Comment: Slade -- yes you showed that, I read too quickly. (And +1 for this part dealing with $a<1$, which maybe can be generalized.)

Comment: Well, if $a\geq 1$, then divide by $2a$, set $g=f/2a$, and work like you did. You will get that $g$ is constant, so $f$ is constant.

Comment: @detnvvp It's slightly more complicated than this, but I think I got it to work.  See the edit.

Comment: Sorry for being slow. How do you use the MVT?

Comment: @user103828 I'm the slow one.  The argument didn't work, so I've reverted it to the one that only works when $a<1$.

Comment: Your second equation is WRONG! Right one is: $$f\left(\frac{x}{N}-1\right)-f\left(\frac{x}{N}\right)=-f'(a_1). $$ And the rest of the argument does not work.

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis It's not my argument; it was dramatically changed while I was asleep.  Actually, it looks equivalent to an argument that I wrote here earlier, but rejected.  Give me a minute.

Comment: Can you expand on the second line of your answer?. If one already knows that the posed function is a constant one, then of course your argument it's true, but without that knowledge, how?

Comment: @derivative Done.  There have been a ton of edits to this question, but I think that what's written now is correct.  Side note: This question is really amazing at getting people to produce incorrect proofs.

Comment: @leo You mean where I conclude that $f$ is differentiable?

Comment: In the case $|\alpha| < 1$, one can also use Banach's fixed point theorem on $$\Gamma : C_b (\Bbb{R})\to C_b (\Bbb{R}),f\mapsto (x\mapsto -a\cdot\int_{x-1}^x f(t)dt),$$ where $C_b (\Bbb{R})$ is the Banach space of bounded continuous functions with the $\Vert\cdot\Vert_\sup$ norm. Then observe that $|\Gamma(x)| =|a|\cdot |\int_{x-1}^x f(t)dt|\leq |a|\cdot \Vert f\Vert_\sup$ and that $\Gamma$ is linear. Hence, $\Gamma$ is contractive, so that $0$ is the unique fixed point. Now note that if $f$ satisfies $f+\Gamma(f) \equiv c$, then $f+k$ is a fixed point of $\Gamma$ for suitable $k \in \Bbb{R}$.

Comment: @PhoemueX Very nice.  I thought that this had a fixed-point feel to it.  It does hint that my argument might not generalize, though.

Comment: I didn't read the question correctly. Now I understand.

Answer (score 4):

As seen in the post of @Slade, there is an easy proof for the case
$a\in\left(0,1\right)$. The general case is more involved and the
only proof I found uses concepts from Fourier Analysis and the theory
of tempered distributions. I will try to explain these a bit, but
I think it will not really be understandable if you have never heard
of these things. So here goes:

By assumption, $f$ is bounded and thus defines a tempered distribution.
It is easy to see (cf. the answer of @Slade for example) that $f$
is continuously differentiable with bounded derivative 
$$
f'\left(x\right)=a\cdot\left[f\left(x-1\right)-f\left(x\right)\right]=a\cdot\left(T_{1}f-f\right)\left(x\right),
$$
where I used the notation $\left(T_{x}f\right)\left(y\right)=f\left(y-x\right)$
for the translation of $f$ by $x$. For the boundedness, simply observe
$$
\left|f'\left(x\right)\right|\leq a\cdot\left[\left|f\left(x-1\right)\right|+\left|f\left(x\right)\right|\right]\leq2a\cdot\left\Vert f\right\Vert _{\sup}<\infty.
$$
Hence, $f\in W^{1,\infty}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$, so that standard
arguments show that the distributional derivative of $f$ coincides
with the ordinary derivative of $f$, considered as a tempered distribution.

In the following, I use the convention
$$
\widehat{g}\left(\xi\right)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}g\left(x\right)\cdot e^{-2\pi i\xi x}\, dx
$$
for the Fourier transform of a function. For a Schwartz-function $g\in\mathcal{S}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$,
partial integration yields
\begin{eqnarray*}
\widehat{g'}\left(\xi\right) & = & \int_{\mathbb{R}}g'\left(x\right)\cdot e^{-2\pi i\xi x}\, dx=-\int_{\mathbb{R}}g\left(x\right)\cdot\frac{d}{dx}e^{-2\pi i\xi x}\, dx\\
 & = & 2\pi i\xi\cdot\int_{\mathbb{R}}g\left(x\right)e^{-2\pi i\xi x}\, dx=2\pi i\xi\cdot\widehat{g}\left(\xi\right).
\end{eqnarray*}
By duality, we conclude
$$
2\pi i\xi\cdot\widehat{f}=\widehat{f'}=\mathcal{F}\left(a\cdot\left[T_{1}f-f\right]\right)=a\cdot\left(M_{-1}\widehat{f}-\widehat{f}\right)=a\cdot\left(e^{-2\pi i\xi}-1\right)\cdot\widehat{f},
$$
where $\left(M_{\omega}g\right)\left(x\right)=e^{2\pi i\omega x}\cdot g\left(x\right)$
denotes the modulation of $g$. It is important to note here that
$\widehat{f}$ might not actually be a (pointwise defined) function,
but is merely a tempered distribution. The distribution $2\pi i\xi\cdot\widehat{f}$
acts on Schwartz functions by
$$
\left\langle 2\pi i\xi\cdot\widehat{f},g\right\rangle _{\mathcal{S}',\mathcal{S}}=\left\langle \widehat{f},2\pi i\xi\cdot g\right\rangle _{\mathcal{S}',\mathcal{S}}.
$$
By rearranging the above identity, we see
$$
\underbrace{\left(a\cdot\left[1-\cos\left(2\pi\xi\right)\right]+i\left(2\pi\xi+a\sin\left(2\pi\xi\right)\right)\right)}_{=:\gamma\left(\xi\right)}\cdot\widehat{f}=\left(2\pi i\xi-a\cdot\left(e^{-2\pi i\xi}-1\right)\right)\cdot\widehat{f}=0.\qquad\left(\dagger\right)
$$
For $\xi\in\mathbb{R}$ with $\gamma\left(\xi\right)=0$, we see (by
only looking at the real part and using $a\neq0$) that $\cos\left(2\pi\xi\right)=1$
and hence $\xi\in\mathbb{Z}$. But this yields $\sin\left(2\pi\xi\right)=0$,
so that (by looking at the imaginary part), we conclude $0=2\pi\xi+a\sin\left(2\pi\xi\right)=2\pi\xi$
and hence $\xi=0$. Note that this also holds in the case $a=0$.
Hence, $\gamma\left(\xi\right)\neq0$ for all $\xi\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\left\{ 0\right\} $.

This implies that the support of the tempered distribution $\widehat{f}$
is a subset of $\left\{ 0\right\} $, because for $g\in C_{c}^{\infty}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$
with $0\notin{\rm supp}\left(g\right)$, we have
$$
\frac{1}{\gamma}\cdot g\in C_{c}^{\infty}\left(\mathbb{R}\right),
$$
because $\gamma$ is smooth and only vanishes at the origin, so that
$$
\left\langle \widehat{f},g\right\rangle _{\mathcal{S}',\mathcal{S}}=\left\langle \gamma\cdot\widehat{f},\frac{1}{\gamma}\cdot g\right\rangle _{\mathcal{S}',\mathcal{S}}\overset{\left(\dagger\right)}{=}\left\langle 0,\frac{1}{\gamma}\cdot g\right\rangle _{\mathcal{S}',\mathcal{S}}=0.
$$

But it is well-known (see for example this post [Distributions supported on a single point](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/236464/distributions-supported-on-a-single-point)
which sadly is missing an answer at the moment) that the only distributions
which are supported at the origin are (in dimension $n=1$) of the
form $\sum_{0\leq\alpha\leq k}c_{\alpha}\cdot\partial^{\alpha}\delta_{0}$
for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and suitable coefficients $c_{\alpha}\in\mathbb{C}$,
where $\delta_{0}$ is the Dirac Delta-distribution at $0$, whose
derivative has again to be understood in the sense of tempered distributions,
i.e. by
$$
\left\langle \partial^{\alpha}\delta_{0},g\right\rangle _{\mathcal{S}',\mathcal{S}}=\left(-1\right)^{\alpha}\cdot\left(\partial^{\alpha}g\right)\left(0\right).
$$
But it is well known (see for example [About the k-th derivative of the Delta function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/601206/about-the-k-th-derivative-of-the-delta-function))
that the inverse Fourier transform of $\partial^{\alpha}\delta_{0}$
is a constant multiple of $\xi^{\alpha}$. Hence, 
$$
f=\mathcal{F}^{-1}\widehat{f}=\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left(\sum_{0\leq\alpha\leq k}c_{\alpha}\cdot\partial^{\alpha}\delta_{0}\right)=\sum_{0\leq\alpha\leq k}\left[c_{\alpha}\cdot\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left(\partial^{\alpha}\delta_{0}\right)\right]
$$
is a polynomial.

But by assumption, $f$ is bounded (on the real line) and the only
bounded polynomials are the constant functions. Hence, $f\equiv{\rm const}$.

It is worth noting that this proof is valid for all $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$,
not only for $\alpha>0$. Also, the same proof shows that $f$ is
a polynomial even if we only assume that $f$ yields a tempered distribution
(i.e. without necessarily assuming that $f$ is bounded).

BTW: It would be interesting to know the actual context in which this problem/exercise occured/was posed, to see if there was some (intended) connection to Fourier analysis.

Once one has seen the idea, it is pretty natural, because the Fourier transform behaves so well with respect to differentiation and translation.

Comment: When I feel that my analysis has been pushed to its limits, it seems I can always count on Fourier to save the day.  It seems that I have some reading to do—though I do agree that this is basically a natural idea.  Without grasping the mechanics of the solution, I can now appreciate that a differential equation involving translation is a perfect candidate for an attack based on the Fourier transform.

Answer (score 2):

Below, we will see that the function $f$ is actually the restriction of an **entire function** to $\Bbb{R}$, i.e. the sume of a convergent power-series with infinite radius of convergence. Once this is shown, the (sadly rather downvoted) answer of @**Leucippus** actually becomes a **valid argument**.

For this, let $K := \Vert f \Vert_\sup$. By assumption, $K < \infty$. We will show by induction on $n \in \Bbb{N}_0$ that $\Vert f^{(n)} \Vert_\sup \leq K \cdot |2a|^n$ for all $n \in \Bbb{N}_0$. For $n=0$ this is trivial.

As also noted in the other posts, continuity of $f$ implies that $x \mapsto \int_{x-1}^x f(t) dt$ is continuously differentiable, which implies that $f$ is continuously differentiable with $f'(x) = -a \cdot (f(x) - f(x-1))$.

By induction, $$f^{(n)}(x) = -a \cdot [f^{(n-1)}(x) - f^{(n-1)}(x-1)].$$

Indeed, for $n=1$, this is what we just noted. In the induction step, we get

$$
f^{(n+1)}(x) = \frac{d}{dx} (-a) \cdot [f^{(n-1)}(x) - f^{(n-1)}(x-1)] = (-a) \cdot [f^{(n)}(x) - f^{(n)}(x-1)].
$$

By induction hypothesis, this yields

$$
|f^{(n+1)}(x)| \leq |a| \cdot [|f^{(n)}(x)| + |f^{(n)}(x-1)|] \leq 2|a| \cdot \Vert f^{(n)} \Vert_\sup \leq |2a|^{n+1}.
$$

But this implies

$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left|\frac{f^{(n)}(0) \cdot x^n}{n!} \right| \leq \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(2|ax|)^n}{n!} = \exp(2|ax|) < \infty,
$$

so that the power series $$g(x) := \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(0) \cdot x^n}{n!}$$ around $0$ of $f$ converges absolutely on all of $\Bbb{R}$.

It remains to show $f = g$. To this end, note that the Lagrange form of the remainder for Taylor's formula (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor's_theorem#Explicit_formulae_for_the_remainder) yields

$$
|f(x) - g(x)| \xleftarrow[k \to \infty]{} \left| f(x) - \sum_{n=0}^k \frac{f^{(n)}(0) x^n}{n!} \right| = \left| \frac{f^{(k+1)}(\xi_L)}{(k+1)!} \cdot |x|^{k+1}\right| \leq \frac{(2|xa|)^{k+1}}{(k+1)!} \xrightarrow[k\to\infty]{} 0,
$$

because even $\sum_k \frac{(2|xa|)^{k+1}}{(k+1)!} = \exp(2|xa|) < \infty$. Hence, $f = g$ is the restriction of an entire function to $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: Ok, I just realized that I am not sure that the argument of Leucippus goes through in the case of power series (instead of polynomials). I will have to think about that.

Comment: I went through a similar series of thoughts yesterday.  I think you're very correct that $f$ is analytic, and this ought to be a huge step towards a solution.  But the functional equation doesn't give some nice recurrence for the coefficients, it gives a bunch of equations all involving infinitely many terms.  This is tricky.

Comment: @Slade: Using the Fourier transform, one can fabricate a proof, see my new answer below :)

Answer (score 1):

Starting with 
\begin{align}
f(x) + a \int_{x-1}^{x} f(t) \, dt = c
\end{align}
then, by differentiation,
\begin{align}
f'(x) + a \left( f(x) - f(x-1) \right) = 0.
\end{align}
Now, for this equation to be satisfied consider it in the form of 
\begin{align}
f'(x) = B = -a ( f(x) - f(x-1) ).
\end{align}
From the equation $f'(x) = B$ it is seen that $f(x) = Bx+c_{1}$. Now, 
\begin{align}
f(x) - f(x-1) &= - \frac{B}{a} \\
(Bx+c_{1}) - (Bx - B + c_{1}) &= - \frac{B}{a} \\
B &= - \frac{B}{a}.
\end{align}
If this is to be satisfied then $B = 0$ which then implies that $$f(x) = c_{1}.$$

---

The alternative is that given the equation
\begin{align}
f'(x) + a (f(x) - f(x-1) ) = 0
\end{align}
then let $f(x) = a_{0} + a_{1} x + a_{2} x^{2} + \cdots$ to obtain
\begin{align}
0 &= [ a_{1} + 2 a_{2} x + \cdots ] + a [ a_{0} + a_{1} x + a_{2} x^{2} + \cdots ] - a[ a_{0} + a_{1} (x-1) + a_{2} (x-1)^{2} + \cdots] \\
&= [ a_{1} + 2 a_{2} x + \cdots] + a[ a_{1} + a_{2}(2x-1) +\cdots] \\
&= [ a_{1} - a(a_{2} - a_{3} + a_{4} - \cdots )] + [ 2 a_{2} + a(2 a_{2} - 3 a_{3} + \cdots) ] x + [ 3(1+a)a_{3} + \cdots ] x^{2} + \cdots .
\end{align}
All the coefficients of $x^{n}$, $0\leq n$, are zero which yields $a_{1} = a_{2} = \cdots = 0$. This then leaves $f(x) = a_{0}$ which is a constant.

Comment: You do need to justify that f is differentiable.   It's not particularly hard,  since if you move the integral to the constant side, the right hand side is differentiable, so thus the left hand side is. Also,  why do you assume that the deriviative is a constant?  And then why are you assuming f has to be a polynomial?

Comment: Why does $f'(x) + a \left( f(x) - f(x-1) \right) = 0$ imply that $f'(x) = B = -a ( f(x) - f(x-1) )$ with some constant $B$?

Answer (score 0):

Write an equation that shows that the derivative of this expression is zero. This way you get an easy differential equation. Show that any solution gives a constant function.

Comment: The equation is $f'(x)+a(f(x)-f(x-1))=0$. I don't think it’s that easy, because there’s the $f(x-1)$ in addition to the derivative

Comment: In Leucippus answer, it is proved that a polynomial which is solution to the equation is necessarily constant. What about the general case?